# Substitution for fixed position using JS

Tags: android, jquery, css, fixed, navbar

i wanna have a floating navbar on my website (the one that scrolls down with you and stays at the top of the window).

the thing is, its for mobile, and when i use fixed position i have an issue with a few android versions (4.3 for example), and my navbar wont go 100% width, it always has a small spacing on the left (seems like a 95% width that floats right).

this is my navbar CSS:

```
#navBar
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666666;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and im also using this on my HTML file:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=100%; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; user-scalable=no;" />
```

i have also tried

```
var documentWidth = $(window).innerWidth();
$('#navBar').width(documentWidth);
```

is there a way to fix this with JS, but without using position fixed? or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try update your css to:

```
#navBar
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666666;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

if it still doesnt work, your option with jquery is:

CSS:

```
#navBar
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #666666;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#navBar').css({'top':$(window).scrollTop(),'left':$(window).scrollLeft()});
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/p44JW/